# 20% OFF all items in category B & Cart Subtotal must be greater than or equal to $200

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

I would like to create a promo code that discounts all skus in category b
However customers must have $200 or more in their cart in order for code to work.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento admin, go to **Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules.**

Select the website and the customer groups you want the discount to be active for. Also select "specific coupon" if you want your customers to add a voucher code in able to activate the discount.

Then click on the tab **Actions**.

Apply: Percent of product price discount
Discount amount: 20

Further down where it says "If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE" you press the green "+"-button and choose Category. Then press the "..." and the list-icon to choose which category the discount will be active in.

Make a new rule after that and choose "Price in cart". Then choose "Equals or greater than". Then press the "..."-button and type 200.

[image]